# What is Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

What is Google Cloud Datastore?

Comment: Hey proppy, it's good to see you trying the self-answer feature of Stack Overflow, but these overtly generalized questions aren't really what we're targeting. It sounds like you're interested in this, so instead, dig into this platform a bit yourself and try to solve a problem with it. Most likely, you'll get stuck on something that others will get stuck on as well. When that happens, come back and post *that* as a question and even self-answer it if you happen to find the answer. This makes for a real, actual problem, which makes a great SO question. Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253 Hey, thanks for taking the time to comment, what I was really trying to do here, is to create a tag for google-cloud-datastore and the associated wiki (I work on the Google Cloud Datastore team). I don't mind the question being closed now that the tag is created.

Comment: Then that puts you in a much better position to write some deeper questions. The best approach I've found is to pretend like you're two different people, a person with a real tough problem that he's beat his head on for hours, and a person who happens to have the answer. Check out the ["Self Answerer's Must Role Play" section of this meta post.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137369/155826). Good luck! :)

Answer (score 7):

[Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore) is a fully managed service for storing non-relational data. It offers the following features:

- built-in query support: flexible query functionality that allows you to search for and filter result sets
- [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transactions: data consistency (both Strong and Eventual) that spans multiple replicas across multiple geos
- automatic scaling: built on top of Google’s [BigTable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) infrastructure, the Google Cloud Datastore will automatically scale with your data
- high availability: by utilizing Google’s underlying [Megastore](http://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2011/Papers/CIDR11_Paper32.pdf) service, the Google Cloud Datastore ensures that data is replicated across multiple geos and is always available
- local development environment: the [Google Cloud Datastore SDK](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver) provides a local environment that allows you to develop, iterate, and manage your Cloud Datastore instances efficiently

You can find the documentation on [developers.google.com/datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore) and follow development on the [GitHub project](http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore).